# What do you call someone who could get used to fear and admiration?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

so I'm reading 'The Sound Of Things Falling' by Juan Gabriel Vásquez and there was a question when reading the text. What do you call someone who could get used to fear and admiration?

"I was barely eight years older than these inexperienced children, but between us opened the double abyss of authority and knowledge, things that I had and they, recently arrived in the world entirely lacked. they admired me, feared me a little and I realised that one could get used to this fear and admiration, that they were like a drug."

Comment: "Egotistical" comes close.

Answer (score -2):

I think

[HORROR FAN](https://horror.media/top-10-blogs-and-websites-for-horror-fans)

is the term you need.

Though it is a bit specific and is limited  to watching horror movies:

Horror fans are "folks who really want the seriously terrifying and creepy on their computer screens will want to check out these specialty websites for horror fans next time you need something terrifying."

Comment: This does not reflect the meaning expressed in the quotation.